# How to optimize a wildcard search with an OR in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, wildcard

I am in a situation where I need to do a wildcard search. Full Text Index is no help as people are searching for part of a word and I can't strip the % from the start of the search to speed it up because they may be searching for the middle part.

There are two fields that need to be searched and a match in either should be returned. If I search for just one field it is very quick (there aren't many rows) but as soon as I search in both it's really slow.

I won't go into details, but to give an idea, when I have

```
... AND (T1.Field1 LIKE '%search%')
```

or

```
... AND (T2.Field1 LIKE '%search%')
```

It takes 0.0695 seconds

but when I do

```
... AND (T1.Field1 LIKE '%search%' OR T2.Field1 LIKE '%search%')
```

it takes 35 seconds

How can I optimize this and why does the OR increase the search time by so much?

The whole, unedited query as requested:

```
SELECT CDR.Status AS CDRStatus, D.VendorID, D.RevisionOfID, D.Revision, D.DocumentID, D.Title, D.OriginalFilename 
FROM Documents AS D
LEFT JOIN CompanyDocumentReviews AS CDR ON CDR.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN Vendors AS V ON V.VendorID = D.VendorID
LEFT JOIN VendorAliases AS VA ON VA.Vendor1ID = V.VendorID AND VA.Vendor2ID != V.VendorID
LEFT JOIN Vendors AS V2 ON V2.VendorID = VA.Vendor2ID
WHERE D.Status != 'Deleted' AND (V1.VendorName LIKE '%search%' OR V2.VendorName LIKE '%search%')
```

Comment: Please show the whole query (at least the part after FROM)

Comment: how are you joining T1 and T2

Comment: whole query added in OP

Answer (score 1):

If a query with just the second condition (T2.Field1 LIKE '%search') also returns quickly, you might try a UNION instead:

```
(SELECT ... AND (T1.Field1 LIKE '%search%'))
UNION
(SELECT ... AND (T2.Field1 LIKE '%search'))
```

Comment: this can return duplicates if record have search and search%

Comment: The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

Comment: Ooops, typo the second search should also have been %search% and yes, they both return quickly when there is no OR. The full query has a bunch of LEFT JOINS that might make a UNION tricky but I might give it a go

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE '%search%'` does not scale, it will require a full table scan, so as your table grows the search will get slower. `LIKE 'search%'` will use an index if one exists on the column and will be much quicker.